# how to check for 'checked' checkbox - php

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send checked value from view to database in checkboxes but system either takes all of them checked or none.
I am using Laravel 5.3 with php 5.
Here is my checkbox view

```
<?php
            foreach($tests as $test) {
                if($test == 1) {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='1' checked/><br>";
                }               
                else {
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check'/><br>";
                }

            }
        ?>
```

And my function to check and attach permission to role is

```
public function updatepermission($id)
{
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permissions = Permission::all();
    $role->permissions()->detach();
    foreach ($permissions as $key) {
        if (Input::get('check') === '1') {
            $role->permissions()->attach($key);
        }
    }
    return redirect('role')->with('message','Permissions has been updated');
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: use `if (Input::has('check'))` instead

Comment: Sry @hassan but still same condition, it either takes all checked or none

Comment: try using check box name in html as array ie. ( check[] )

Comment: as @rajeshk said, you need to define your checkbox name as an array `check[]` as long as you are use foreach to create your checkbox

Comment: still no luck for me. I tried all your suggestion. Do i need to provide something else @RajeshK

Comment: Do your checkboxes have unique names? And what is the difference in `$request->all()` when you print them to the screen?

Comment: No. I don't have unique name for all the checkboxes. All of them have name as "check[]" @DouwedeHaan

Comment: Ah okay. Your problem is that you check if an input equals 1, while the value is an array. You should name your checkboxes and loop through the inputs while updating the permissions. I'll try to create an answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question**

The method to test if an checkbox has been checked in a form is the following piece of code:

```
if (Input::has('check')) {
    // your logic here
}
```

After answering your question, I notice a the problem in your code where you want to attach permissions to a role. I wrote a fix for that if you're interested:

**Fixing part**

I'm fairly certain that you have a page where you set the permissions for a role. This means that there is only one role, but multiple permissions. I suggest you do this in your view:

```
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
    @if ($role->permissions()->contains($permission))
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="permissions[{{ $permission->id }}]" checked>
    @else
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="permissions[{{ $permission->id }}]">
    @endif
@endforeach
```

And the following in your controller:

```
public function updatepermission(Request $request, $id) {
    $role = Role::find($id);
    $permissions = $request->input('permissions', []);
    $permissionIds = array_keys($permissions);


    $role->permissions()->sync($permissionIds);
    return redirect('role')->with('message','Permissions has been updated');
}
```